# Mocha Chai wait for modal to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mocha.js, chai

How can I ask mocha/chai to wait for a modal to be shown before it expects the test to be complete?

I am wrapping bootstrap modal and emitting my own events. `show` works fine, but I need to wait for the modal to be `shown` for my next test. I can't get `done()` to work at all.

```
describe("Modal", function() {
    describe("wrapModalEvents", function() {
        it("should wrap the show.bs.modal event", function() {
            var m = new Modal();
            m.wrapModalEvents();
            var res = {e:1};
            m.on('show', function(){
                res.e = 555;
            });
            m.modal();
            expect(res.e).to.equal(555);
        });
        it("should wrap the shown.bs.modal event", function() {
            var m = new Modal();
            m.wrapModalEvents();
            var res = {e:1};
            m.on('shown', function(){
                res.e = 123;
            });
            // need to wait at least one second
            expect(res.e).to.equal(123);
        });
    });
});
```